JFrog Artifactory How To Block Download
I want to block JFrog Artifactory download at some situation，like name has "testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",so I write a groovy at artifactory/plugins/ ,like this:
download {
    altResponse { request, responseRepoPath ->
        log.warn("altResponse")
        def fileName = responseRepoPath.getName()
        log.warn "altResponse status: ${status},fileName:${fileName}"
        if (fileName.contains("testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")){
            log.warn "altResponse name contains: ${fileName}"
            status = 403 
            message = "can't download"
            log.warn "altResponse newstatus: ${status}"
        }else {
            log.warn("fileName not contains")
        }
    }
}

when I finish set this,I can't download:testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar on UI , is fit what I want,
but when I use terminal:
curl -O http://xxxxxx/artifactory/cid-maven-local/testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
, Jfrog log/console.log show me :
altResponse  
altResponse status: -1,fileName:testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
altResponse name contains: testmaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
altResponse newstatus: 403
Sending HTTP error code 403: can't download

but I still see file download to my Folder，how can I do?
I want to know what should I do ?
I refer to this：
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/plugin-template-source

Can you verify the content of the file. If I anticipate correctly, that is just a file wth the content "File can't be downloaded". If not there must be an issue. Can you verify the contents of the file? You may just "vi" or "vim" file to see the contents.

you are right!! I change to download another file setting.xml,and the content is {
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 403,
"message" : "can't download"
} ]
},so it will still download the file, jest content change? can I don't let it download the file??? thank you~

Since you are using -O command to place in a file, it creates a file with whatever content it receives.

yes~when I delete -o ,it works~thanks you!!
